# Nested Parcelling : RuntimeException - Unmarshalling unknown type code 3211319 at offset 440

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I need to send some data to an `Activity`, which may be running in different context.
For this I created a class say A, which has an `ArrayList` of datatype say B as its one of instance member . I declared class B as Class A's Inner class. To send this class A's instance through `Intent`, I made class A and B both `Parcelable`.

Class structure is something like this (this does not include the complete code e.g. code written to make the classes `Parcelable`):

```
public class A implements Parcelable{

   public class B implements Parcelable{
         public ArrayList<String> value;
         ....
         .... 
          public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeList(value);
           }
        ....
        ....
   }

   public List<B> group;
   public String name;

   ....
   .... 
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeList(group);
        dest.writeString(name);
       }
   ....
   ....
}
```

I used the `putExtra (String name, Parcelable value)` function to put data.

But on the receiving side, I got the following exception:

```
 Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087): 1289817569622 java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.SET_VOIP_SUPP_SERVICE_REQUEST_LOCAL (has extras) } in com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.MyAppActuvity$1@43b409b0
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:765)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@43b51240: Unmarshalling unknown type code 3211319 at offset 440
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1777)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readList(Parcel.java:1302)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.A.<init>(A.java:61)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.A.<init>(A.java:57)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.A$1.createFromParcel(A.java:67)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.A$1.createFromParcel(A.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1845)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1713)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:1947)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:169)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1037)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:3269)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at com.hsc.example.android.MyApp.MyAppActuvity$1.onReceive(MyAppActuvity.java:219)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(ActivityThread.java:754)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1087):        ... 9 more
```

Then I moved the class B, outside the class A (As I thought this may be problem of inner class, and declared the CREATOR static. This static declaration was not present when class B was an inner class of Class A). But it did not helped.

This seems that this problem is due to nested Parceling.

Any suggestion ??

**NOTE**: when I used `android.os.Bundle.putParcelable(String key, Parcelable value)` function of Bundle class, and then unmarshalled it using `android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(String key)` then everything is fine. So it seems that the problem is with respect to Intents only.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I seem to be having to deal with a similar scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Did you include the CREATOR in for both?

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<A> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<A>() {
   public A createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new A(in);
      }

   public A[] newArray(int size) {
      return new A[size];
      }
};
```

& constructors that take a Parcel:

```
public A(Parcel parcel) {
   name = parcel.readString();
   //etc..
}
```

?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `List<B>` to `ArrayList<B>`
2. Use `writeTypedList` and `readTypedList` to write and read ArrayList